# Any way to get breakpoint-specific width classes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4 includes the [width classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/):

```
w-25
w-50
w-75
w-100
```

I want to specify widths only for certain breakpoints and above; e.g., "w-md-25", etc.

Is it possible to add such classes in the SCSS files, or otherwise get this functionality?

Comment: Should be easy enough to add to your own SCSS, using Bootstrap's `_sizing.scss` as a guide.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know much about Sass, but with your comment (and a bit of poking around) I was able to figure it out.

Comment: A related feature request, currently being ignored: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26528

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66758895/633961 (work-around via `min-width` and `max-width`)

Answer (score 18):

Got it figured out with Blazemonger's help. I added this to my custom.scss file, recompiled, and it worked beautifully:

```
@each $breakpoint in map-keys($grid-breakpoints) {
  @each $size, $length in $sizes {
    @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
      .w-#{$breakpoint}-#{$size} {width: $length !important;}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had to add this for your code to work
$sizes: (
 25: 25%,
 50: 50%,
 75: 75%,
 100: 100%,
); But it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In the 'ugly as sin' solution category, if you don't want to play with SCSS you can do things like:

```
<!-- Show at 100% width on xs devices. Hide (d-sm-none) on sm and above -->
<element class="w-100 d-sm-none">

<!-- Hide on xs devices. Show normally on sm and above -->
<element class="d-none d-sm-flex">
```

Depending upon the complexity of what you are trying to achieve, this can be a workaround. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/display/#hiding-elements for more detail on hiding selectively.

Answer (score 7):

So I did found another proper solution. You will have to override the utilities.scss with your own.

Just add after the import of the utilities.scss the snippet below ([Docs for Bootstrap API](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/api/#using-the-api)). You can define even another values (I did add 33 and 66):

```
$utilities: map-merge(
  $utilities,
  (
    'width': (
      property: width,
      class: w,
      responsive: true,
      values: (
        25: 25%,
        33: 33%,
        50: 50%,
        66: 66%,
        75: 75%,
        100: 100%,
        auto: auto,
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

The trick for the breakpoints is the addition of `responsive: true,` which will add those breakpoints prefixes later on in `utilities/api`.

Comment: Perfect Solution!!! Bootstrap 5.1

Answer (score 2):

Using bootstrap 5.2, same as user1501025, but I use override to make it works.

```
$utilities: (
  'width': (
    property: width,
    class: w,
    responsive: true,
    values: (
      25: 25%,
      33: 33%,
      50: 50%,
      66: 66%,
      75: 75%,
      100: 100%,
      auto: auto,
    ),
  )
);

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```