# Bootstrap: sizing depending on Viewport

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootstrap5 Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/sizing/) does not support sizing depending on the viewport.

I would like to have this:

- on small devices the width should be 100%
- on larger devices the width should be 75%
- on extra large devices the width should be 50%

The corresponding feature request was closed: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/26528

How to work around this missing feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to get breakpoint-specific width classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760132/any-way-to-get-breakpoint-specific-width-classes)

Answer (score 2):

For me using `min-width` and `max-width` was a usable work-around:

```html
<div style="min-width: 20em; max-width: 40em; border: 1px solid">...</div>
```